# Wikidata SPARQL query returns wrong results

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, wikidata

[This query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP54%20wd%3AQ18656.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP54%20wd%3AQ75729.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP54%20wd%3AQ8682.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D), why does it return Gabriel Heinze and not Cristiano Ronaldo? Both satisfy the criteria

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P54 wd:Q18656.
  ?person wdt:P54 wd:Q75729.
  ?person wdt:P54 wd:Q8682.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Querying [clubs Cristiano Ronaldo is member of](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Fclubs%20%3FclubsLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fclub%20%3FclubLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ11571%20wdt%3AP54%20%3Fclub%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100), using `wdt` as property prefix returns only the [Real Madrid FC](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q8682) as this statement has a [higher priority rank](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Ranking#What_ranks_are_for), and [`wdt` focuses on the highest priority rank statements](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#US_presidents_and_their_spouses).

Unfortunatly, there is no direct substitute to `wdt` that would include lower priority statements, but you can use a combination of `p` and `ps`:

- [the fixed query to find all clubs Ronaldo has been part of](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fclub%20%3FclubLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ11571%20p%3AP54%20%3Fclub_statement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fclub_statement%20ps%3AP54%20%3Fclub%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)
- [your query fixed](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20p%3AP54%20%3Fclub_a_statement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fclub_a_statement%20ps%3AP54%20wd%3AQ18656%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20p%3AP54%20%3Fclub_b_statement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fclub_b_statement%20ps%3AP54%20wd%3AQ75729%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20p%3AP54%20%3Fclub_c_statement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fclub_c_statement%20ps%3AP54%20wd%3AQ8682%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Thanks for asking: researching, I finally learned what the `t` stands for in `wdt`: *truthy* \o/